# How to use this.$refs in vue ts that error Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I need to use  this.$refs.calendars.$refs.calendar.showPageRange() in js it work but in ts that error '$refs' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'

```
 <v-date-picker
  v-model="dates"
  ref="calendars"
 />
```

ts

```
interface Data {
  dates?: { start: Date; end: Date };
 } 
export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
   VDatePicker: () => import('v-calendar/lib/components/date-picker.umd')
  },
   data(): Data {
    return {
      dates: undefined
     };
   },
```

in methods

```
    this.$refs.calendars.$refs.calendar.showPageRange({
    from: this.dates.end
  })
```

```
Property '$refs' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | Vue[] | Element[]'.
```

Comment: Could it be because typescript doesn't know exactly what type `this.$refs.calendars` is? Refs can be any of those 4 alternatives, you probably need an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I look back my previous answer and realize how stupid I was.

Now I know that $ref.xxx might have found a type of `Vue` or `Element`

You could simply add an assertion like this

```
(this.$refs.calendars as Vue).$refs.calendar.showPageRange({
  from: this.dates.end
})
```

or

```
(this.$refs.calendars as VDatePicker).$refs.calendar.showPageRange({
  from: this.dates.end
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//(I was using a QSelect quasar element)..
<template>
 <q-select ref="selector"> </q-select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { QSelect } from 'quasar';

$refs!: {
    selector: QSelect;
};
mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            (this.$refs.selector).showPopup();
        });
    }
<script>
```